# How to update a new column with only a piece of text from another column - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to pull only part of the value from one column: "CI_Support_Remarks" to update another column "Asset_Number" in my table "CI_Information". If the data is currently stored as:

"Asset#: 33800000125Primary support:Persons nameSecondary support....ect"

How do I only pull the number following "Asset#:" and nothing else to update the Asset Number column. I am only trying to update the Asset column and not affect the CI_Support_Remarks column.

As a note all the asset numbers are the same length and stored in the same format.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use `substr()`:

```
update t
    set asset_number = substr(CI_Support_Remarks, 9, 11);
```

Comment: Is there a way to only get it to select the numbers directly following "Asset#:" is seems some of the rows have additional information or are off by a few places. I am dealing with over 200,000 records so I can't alter the code for each variation.

Comment: @CNC773 . . . I suggested a simple `substr()` because the question explicitly states:  "As a note all the asset numbers are the same length and stored in the same format.".  If you have another question, please ask it as a question with sample data and desired results.